# Get average color of image without sacrificing lazy loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, lazy-loading

Here is just an example of what I'm trying to achieve.
[image: example of getting color from image]

So I looked online on how to get the average color of an image and the solution I found works pretty well. The only problem is that it doesn't work well when you decide to lazy load the images.

For the purpose of this question, here is a basic HTML structure with images.

```
<div id="block">
    <img id="img" class="cimg" src="http://localhost:90/avg-color-of-img/Archive.jpg">
</div>

<div id="block">
    <img id="img" class="cimg" src="http://localhost:90/avg-color-of-img/Archive.jpg">
</div>

<div id="block">
    <img id="img" class="cimg" src="http://localhost:90/avg-color-of-img/Archive.jpg">
</div>
```

And here is the javascript that picks the average color from the images:

```
function averageColor(imageElement) {
    // Create the canavs element
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),

    // Get the 2D context of the canvas
    context
        = canvas.getContext &&
        canvas.getContext('2d'),
        imgData, width, height,
        length,
 
        // Define variables for storing
        // the individual red, blue and
        // green colors
        rgb = { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 },

        // Define variable for the 
        // total number of colors
        count = 0;
 
    // Set the height and width equal
    // to that of the canvas and the image
    height = canvas.height =
        imageElement.naturalHeight ||
        imageElement.offsetHeight ||
        imageElement.height;
    width = canvas.width =
        imageElement.naturalWidth ||
        imageElement.offsetWidth ||
        imageElement.width;
 
    // Draw the image to the canvas
    context.drawImage(imageElement, 0, 0);
 
    // Get the data of the image
    imgData = context.getImageData(
            0, 0, width, height);

    // Get the length of image data object
    length = imgData.data.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i += 4) {
        // Sum all values of red colour
        rgb.r += imgData.data[i];

        // Sum all values of green colour
        rgb.g += imgData.data[i + 1];

        // Sum all values of blue colour
        rgb.b += imgData.data[i + 2];

        // Increment the total number of
        // values of rgb colours
        count++;
    }

    // Find the average of red
    rgb.r = Math.floor(rgb.r / count);

    // Find the average of green
    rgb.g = Math.floor(rgb.g / count);

    // Find the average of blue
    rgb.b = Math.floor(rgb.b / count);

    return rgb;
}
// Function to set the background color of the second div as 
// calculated average color of image
var rgb;
var imgg = document.getElementsByClassName("cimg");
var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName("block");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < imgg.length; i++) {
    rgb = averageColor(imgg[I]);

    blocks[i].style.backgroundColor =
        'rgb(' + rgb.r + ','
        + rgb.g + ','
        + rgb.b + ')';
}
```

Everything worked fine until I decided to use 'lazysizes' to lazyload the images.

For the lazy loading to work I had to use `data-src` to get the images instead of the regular `src` attribute and now because there isn't an image in the `src` attribute, the code to pick the average color doesn't work well.

Please is there any possible way to lazy load images and still get their average color?
Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want the color to show up before the image loads or once the image loads? (The latter option is a lot simpler.)

Comment: @code yes once the image loads

Comment: By the way, (sorry, this is just my nature), it's beginners, not begginers or begginners. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a load event listener for each image, so once each image loads you get the color. Your code can be written thus:

```js
var imgg = document.getElementsByClassName("cimg");
var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName("block");
for (var i = 0; i < imgg.length; i++) {
    setColor(i);
}

function setColor(i) {
  var $img = imgg[i];
  // once the lazy-loaded image loads:
  $img.addEventListener("load", e => {
    // get average color and set
    var rgb = averageColor($img);
    blocks[i].style.backgroundColor =
          'rgb(' + rgb.r + ','
          + rgb.g + ','
          + rgb.b + ')';
  });
}
```

Comment: @ZeddyEmy good for you :) Happy coding!