# Get the average color of an image before it loads on the page

Tags: javascript, html, image, lazy-loading, background-color

I have javascript code that gets the average colour of an image.
But the issue now is that it doesn't work well with lazyloading.

***btw I found a similar question [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71388641/get-average-color-of-image-without-sacrificing-lazy-loading) but mine is a little different.***

Below is the HTML code I used:

```
<div class="box">
    <img class="the-img" src="http://localhost:90/image.jpg">
</div>

<div class="box">
    <img class="the-img" src="http://localhost:90/image.jpg">
</div>

<div class="box">
    <img class="the-img" src="http://localhost:90/image.jpg">
</div>
```

And this is the script that picks the average color from the image:

```
function averageColor(imageElement) {
    // Create the canavs element
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),

    // Get the 2D context of the canvas
    context
        = canvas.getContext &&
        canvas.getContext('2d'),
        imgData, width, height,
        length,

    // Define variables for storing
    // the individual red, blue and
    // green colors
    rgb = { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 },

    // Define variable for the 
    // total number of colors
    count = 0;

    // Set the height and width equal
    // to that of the canvas and the image
    height = canvas.height =
        imageElement.naturalHeight ||
        imageElement.offsetHeight ||
        imageElement.height;
    width = canvas.width =
        imageElement.naturalWidth ||
        imageElement.offsetWidth ||
        imageElement.width;

    // Draw the image to the canvas
    context.drawImage(imageElement, 0, 0);

    // Get the data of the image
    imgData = context.getImageData(
        0, 0, width, height);

   // Get the length of image data object
   length = imgData.data.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i += 4) {
        // Sum all values of red colour
        rgb.r += imgData.data[i];

        // Sum all values of green colour
        rgb.g += imgData.data[i + 1];

        // Sum all values of blue colour
        rgb.b += imgData.data[i + 2];

        // Increment the total number of
        // values of rgb colours
        count++;
    }

    // Find the average of red
    rgb.r = Math.floor(rgb.r / count);

    // Find the average of green
    rgb.g = Math.floor(rgb.g / count);

    // Find the average of blue
    rgb.b = Math.floor(rgb.b / count);

    return rgb;
}

// Function to use the calculated average color of image
// as the background color of the box div
var rgb;
var imgg = document.getElementsByClassName("the-img");
var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
var I;
for (i = 0; i < imgg.length; i++) {
    rgb = averageColor(imgg[I]);
    blocks[i].style.backgroundColor =
        'rgb(' + rgb.r + ','
        + rgb.g + ','
        + rgb.b + ')';
}
```

When I decided to lazy load the images the above code did work.
I searched for possible solutions to this and I found that someone with a very similar issue already asked a question [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71388641/get-average-color-of-image-without-sacrificing-lazy-loading).

Apparently, the code isn't working because there is no image in the src attribute when lazyloading.

But the answer he requested was a way to pick the average colour after the image had loaded.
And the answer he got was to create a load event listener for each image. Like this:

```
var imgg = document.getElementsByClassName("the-img");
var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

for (var i = 0; i < imgg.length; i++) {
    setColor(I);
}
function setColor(i) {
    var $img = imgg[I];

   // once the lazy-loaded image loads:
   $img.addEventListener("load", e => {
       // get average color and set
       var rgb = averageColor($img);
       blocks[i].style.backgroundColor =
          'rgb(' + rgb.r + ','
          + rgb.g + ','
          + rgb.b + ')';
  });
}
```

But in my case, I'm wondering if it's possible to get the average colour of the image even before it loads on the page. I know it might be a little complicated to achieve but Can anyone assist with this or point me in the right direction.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can't get the average colour of the image the same way, as it requires you to load the image first in order to get the colours of all of its pixels and average them together --- you obviously can't just compute that ex nihilo, as you won't have any of the pixel data to base your calculation off of.

There's a few ways this can typically be solved:

- If the images are static (you always know you're going to be loading the same images every time), you could precompute their average colours and just hard-code it alongside the source. It's a boring solution, but it does work.

  - Alternatively, you could consider making two copies of each image, one which is a "thumbnail" image that's really small (e.g. 10 by 10 pixels wide). You could load that immediantly and figure out its average colour, and then still get the benefits of lazy loading in the full image when you need to.
- If the images are being loaded dynamically (e.g. you're pulling them from a database etc on the backend), then you'll already be doing something to inject in the URLs here. Thus, it would be pretty easy to just move the colour average computation to the backend (you could even store it in the database when the images are first uploaded), and then provide it to the frontend at the same time that you provide the image's URL.