# Getting dominant color of each image and using it as a background

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, colors, background

I'm new to vue.js and I have here multiple cards/posters. I want to get the dominant color of the images coming from the PicturesUrl and apply it in customcard-short. Since the images are inside the customcard, it will have different images per boxes/card which means it will have different dominant colors per box as their background in customcard-short. It is supposed to be the same as the output in the link. I also tried applying those code from the link to my own code but it just removes all the images and didn't give me the dominant color. How can I achieve this? I'm really new and hoping that someone can help me with this.

[Get average color of image without sacrificing lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71388641/get-average-color-of-image-without-sacrificing-lazy-loading)

```
<template>
  <div class="customcard">
    <el-image
      :lazy="true"
      class="custom-poster"
      :src="PicturesUrl + info.customTableImage"
    />
      
    <img  v-if="corner" :src="require(`@/assets/custom/${corner}.png`)" class="custom-corner">
    <!-- <h1>{{ corner }}</h1> -->
    <div class="customcard-main">
          <div class="customcard-main-tit">
            <img :src="PicturesUrl + info.customIconImage" class="customcard-icon" />
            <span>{{ $t(getKey(info.customName)) }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="customcard-short">
            <div class="custom-cont">
            <div class="customcard-main-cont">
              {{ info["Description"] }}
            </div>

            <div class="details">
            </div>

            <div class="flags">
            </div>

            <div class="label">
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
            <div class="customcard-btn" @click="goDetails(info)">
            <div class="btn-text">try</div>
            </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</template>



<script>
export default {
  name: "Cards",
  props: {
    info: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {},
    },
  },
  data(){
    return {
      corner:''
    }
  },
  created(){
    console.log('info', this.info, this.PicturesUrl)
    const cornerEmum = {'a':'new','b':'new','c':'hot'}
    this.corner = cornerEmum[this.info.labelName]
  },
  setup() {
    return {
      PicturesUrl: window.PicturesUrl,
      Details({ id }) {
        window.open(`/gdetails/${id}/custom`);
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.customcard {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 450px;
  width: 350px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #ddd;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  //cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: move_opacity 0.5s ease 1 forwards;
  &:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  &:hover {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  .custom-poster {
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px; //253
  }
  .custom-corner{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 81px;
  }
  .customcard-main {
    height: 302px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background: rgba(93, 37, 8, 0.09);
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-255px); 
    overflow: hidden;
    //cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0s;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: move_opacity 0.5s ease 1 forwards;
    margin: 0 auto;
    .customcard-short{
    width: 100%;
    height: 254px;
    //flex-shrink: 0;
    //background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(93, 37, 8, 0.08) 0%, #5D2508 27.56%);
    backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
    transform: translateY(-12px); 
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .custom-cont{
      padding: 0 20px;
    }
    &:hover {
      transform: translateY(-307px);
    }

    .customcard-main-tit {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      transform: translateY(-7px); //-2
      color: #fff;
      padding: 0 20px;

      .customcard-icon {
        transform: translateY(-16px);
        display: flex;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        margin-right: 12px;
      }
      span {
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 25.2px;
        font-weight: 500;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-line-clamp: 1;
      }
    }

    .customcard-main-cont {
      margin-top: 5px;
      width: 100%;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #fff;
      transform: translateY(-2px);
      overflow: hidden;
      display: -webkit-box;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    } 
      .flags {
      margin-top: 5px;
      align-items: center;
      transform: translateY(35px);
      overflow: hidden;
      display: -webkit-box;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .logo1-icon{
      width: 100px;
      margin-right: 8px;
    }
    .logo2-icon{
      width:100px;
      margin-right: 22px;
    }
    .cn-icon{
      width: 30px;
    }
    .en-icon{
      width:30px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }


    .details{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      //align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(15px);
    }
    .label{
      align-items: center;
      font-weight: 400;
      color: #fff;
      transform: translateY(35px);//233
      overflow: hidden;
      display: -webkit-box;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    }

    .customcard-btn{
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 52px;
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.10);
      backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
      font-weight: 400;
      border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .btn-text{
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 400;
      padding-top: 12px;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .cert, .lang{
      font-size: 12px;
      font-weight: 400;
    }
    .cert{
      margin-right: 162px;
      }
  }

  @keyframes move_opacity {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: @Yogi, yes but don't know how to apply it.