# How to make an image fade out (solid to transparent)

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

Is it even possible to make images linear-gradient? Like it will be solid image at the bottom and transparent on the top? I have here an image that I made 50 times bigger than its size to make it look like it is a color from an image. But I want the top of it to be transparent so that the image below will be visible. The image below will be the image from Custom-poster and the image that needs to look like linear-gradient is the .background-image url (solid color at the bottom and transparent on the top which will make like a fading color). Please help me achieve this one.

```
<template>
<div class="Customcard">
<el-image
:lazy="true"
class="Custom-poster"
:src="imagesLink + info.CustomTableImage"
/>

<img v-if="corner" :src="require(`@/assets/Custom/${corner}.png`)" class="Custom-corner">
<!-- <h1>{{ corner }}</h1> -->
<div class="Customcard-main">
<div class="Customcard-main-tit">
<img :src="imagesLink + info.CustomIconImage" class="Customcard-icon" />
<span>{{ $t(getKey(info.CustomName)) }}</span>
</div>
<div class="Customcard-short" v-for="(url, index) in imageLinks" :key="index">
<div class="background-image-div">
<div class="background-image" :style="{ background: `url(${url})`, }"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: "Boxes",
props: {
info: {
type: Object,
default: () => {},
},
},
data(){
return {
corner: '',
imageLinks: [] // Add this line to store image URLs
}
},
created(){
console.log('info', this.info, this.imagesLink)
const cornerEmum = {'a':'new','b':'new','c':'hot'}
this.corner = cornerEmum[this.info.labelName]
},
mounted() {
// Get all images and store their URLs in the imageLinks array
const images = this.$el.getElementsByTagName('img');
this.imageLinks = Array.from(images).map(img => img.src);
console.log(this.imageLinks); 

},
setup() {
return {
imagesLink: window.imagesLink,
goDetails({ id }) {
window.open(`/CustomDetails/${id}/Custom`);
},
};
},
};
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.Customcard {
display: inline-block;
height: 450px;
width: 350px;
border-radius: 20px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
margin-right: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
transition: all 0.3s;
opacity: 0;
animation: move_opacity 0.5s ease 1 forwards;
&:nth-child(3n) {
margin-right: 0;
}
&:hover {
transform: translateY(-10px);
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #ddd;
}
.Custom-poster {
width: 100%;
height: 450px;
}
.Custom-corner{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 81px;
}
.Customcard-main {
height: 302px;
flex-shrink: 0;
background: rgba(93, 37, 8, 0.09);
backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 100%;
transform: translateY(-255px); 
//overflow: hidden;
//cursor: pointer;
transition: all 0s;
opacity: 0;
animation: move_opacity 0.5s ease 1 forwards;
margin: 0 auto;
.Customcard-short{
width: 100%;
height: 254px;
//flex-shrink: 0;
//background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(93, 37, 8, 0.08) 0%, #5D2508 27.56%);
backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
transform: translateY(-12px); 
margin: 0 auto;
}

.background-image-div {
position: relative;
height: 254px;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
.background-image {
width: 302px;
height: 254px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
filter: blur(50px);
transform: scale(50);
position: center;
//background-size: cover; /* This will make the background image cover the entire area of the div */
}

.Custom-cont{
padding: 0 20px;
transform: translateY(-240px);
}
&:hover {
transform: translateY(-307px);
}


.Customcard-main-tit {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
transform: translateY(-7px); //-2
color: #fff;
padding: 0 20px;

.Customcard-icon {
transform: translateY(-16px);
display: flex;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
margin-right: 12px;
}
span {
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 25.2px;
font-weight: 500;
overflow: hidden;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-line-clamp: 1;
}
}

.Customcard-main-cont {
margin-top: 5px;
width: 100%;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 14px;
color: #fff;
transform: translateY(-2px);
overflow: hidden;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
} 
}

@keyframes move_opacity {
from {
opacity: 0;
}
to {
opacity: 1;
}
}
}
</style>
```

Comment: There is way too much code that is irrelevant to the problem. Vue is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: @gre-gor , I'm actually looking something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71388641/get-average-color-of-image-without-sacrificing-lazy-loading but since I have limited knowledge in javascript, I tried to improvise that the custom-poster will be the image at the back and the .background-image is the linear-gradient. Sadly, I can't make the top of the .background-image images transparent on the  since I only copy the image from the imagesLink.

Comment: That doesn't require transparent image, only regular transparent gradient. Neither is JavaScript needed here, only CSS.

Comment: [Semi-transparent color layer over background-image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9182978)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand what you want... But it looks like you're looking for the `mask-image` property. Something like this:

```css
.images {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.images img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.images img:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(red 25%, transparent 75%);
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/28/200/200" class="masked-img" alt="">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/23/200/200" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: I actually follow the output of this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71388641/get-average-color-of-image-without-sacrificing-lazy-loading in which the imagesLink is the image in the back and the .background-image is the one I want to be linear-gradient. That's why I made the image transform: scale to zoom in the pixels and make it look like a color. Then I wanted to make the top part of it transparent so it will look like fading at the top. This can be achievable with colorthief though I'm not really used to javascript and I'm new in vue.js. hoping you can help me achieve this.